# Setting Up Node on Production Server

Tags: linux, centos, node.js

I Really need some help. I have this centos 6 or 7 server. I have set up my nodejs app and run on the server on port 8080.

netstat also output it

```
weshop@host [~]# netstat -an | grep "LISTEN " | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

my nodejs app work correctly on my local but on my server it just keep showing an error

> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: what client is it that is giving you that error? Remote PC? same server? If it is a remote, what is the network between the client/server

Comment: my pc. not same server

Comment: how is your PC connected to your server? Same network? or through a firewall or router? Try a `tracert` to your server's IP/Domain (What ever you are using to connect to it in the client)

Comment: not the same network. my server is hosted at hostgator and I am using my pc at home.

Comment: Last Question: What is your hosting package? Dedicated virtual server? or just a web server?

Comment: You need to forward port 8080 on your server, which will require hostgator's support team. You can read more about their procedure here: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-policies/open-new-ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 8080 is currently not accessible outside of your server's network. You will need to forward that port to your server to fix your issue.

Comment: Which node function would the user need to use to forward the port to the server?